# Вывод элементов согласно подразделам

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть инфоблок с разделами, подразделами и элементами в нем.

**Используется компонент Catalog.**

Как мне сделать так, чтоб когда перехожу на подраздел то открывается стр. 2 с тем разделом и подразделами на который я перешел?

Выводилось меню с названием раздела и как кнопки(ссылки) на его подразделы и элементы согласно подразделу на который перешел.

Как мне правильно реализовать такое меню. (Сейчас это компонент catalog.section.list).

Или как мне передать в него SECTION_ID или SECTION_CODE того раздела в котором я нажал подраздел?

Чтоб (**catalog.section.list**) выводил из нужного мне раздела подразделы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее спасибо.
Если есть какие-то идеи или решение, буду благодарен.

Comment: То что Вы описываете есть в стандартном компоненте `bitrix:catalog`, если хочется поиграться, скопируйте его к себе и его "подкомпоненты" и играйтесь, меняйте дизайн, логику

Comment: Я и так использую этот компонент, вопрос в другом.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех у кого будет похожая проблема, вот решение.

Этот код надо вставить в (section.php) в самом вверху перед вызовом (catalog.section.list).

Небольшое пояснения:

Я беру (SECTION_ID) как и стандартный компонент из массива ($arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_ID"]) и проверяю к какому родителю(разделу) он относится, получаю ID родителя и передаю в (catalog.section.list), а если это и есть родитель то беру его ID.

```
$obj_res =  CIBlockSection::GetList(array () , array("IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], "ID" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_ID"]), false);
if ( $parent_id = $obj_res->GetNext() ):
    if (isset($parent_id["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"])):
        $sectionId = $parent_id["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"];
    else:
        $sectionId = $parent_id['ID'];
    endif;
endif;
?>
```